# How do you find the area of the shaded area of this circle?

Tags: geometry

[image: circle with triangle inscribed in it]

I need to find the area of the shaded area. The triangle is equilateral. So far, I have found the area of the triangle to be $\sqrt 3$, but I cannot figure out how to find the radius of the circle in order to find the area of the circle. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the triangle equilateral?

Comment: Yes it is equilateral.

Comment: Do you know how to find the areas of circles and triangles? Oops, sorry, I see that you do. My bad. Try drawing in a radius and looking for relationships. Hint: Choose your radius wisely.

Comment: Lookup [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment), and think what all that comes down to for an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're looking for the radius right? So let's draw them..

[image]

Please excuse the drawing.

Ok. Now we have an isosceles triangle $30-30-120$. If  $r$ is the radius then law of sines tells us,

$$\frac{2}{\sin 120}=\frac{r}{\sin 30}$$

So $r=2 \frac{\sin 30}{\sin 120}=2\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got about 1.15 feet squared as the radius. Now I can do the rest.

Comment: My final answer is about 2.5 feet squared. Is this correct?

Comment: You're welcome. That's about right. The exact answer is $\frac{4}{3}\pi-\sqrt{3}$ feet squared. @JustinLam

Comment: Ahmed's drawing:  cos(30°) = 1/r. Hence r = 1/cos(30°). Using cos(30°) = (1/2)×(√3) we get r.

Comment: Interesting, didn't see that @Peter Szilas. If one is wondering extend the  the vertical black line we drew down. One can show it will bisect the bottom side into two equal parts. Then just apply cosine as usual with either triangle (there are two) created by extended the vertical line.

Comment: Perhaps you may formulate that as an answer because it's adds another perspective and sheds some more light onto the problem. @Peter Szilas

Comment: @Ahmed. You want to add it in your answer as an other option?

Comment: I was just encouraging that you write another answer, if you can, it would be nice. @PeterSzilas

Comment: @Ahmed. OK , here we go.

Answer (score 1):

Let's label Ahmed's drawing: Triangle $ABC$, lower left $A$, then counterclockwise $B$, and $C$ (top). Let the center of the circle be $M$. Extend $CM$ to intersect $AB$ in $D$. Note length $AD$ $=$ length $DB$ $=1$, $MD$ being the perpendicular bisector of $AB$. Triangle $ADM$ is a right angled triangle. Angle $MAD = 30°$.

$$\cos (30°) = \frac{1}{r}$$

$$r = \frac{1}{\cos (30°)}$$

Using $\cos (30°) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ we get $r$.